# Drupal crash recovery - segmentation fault

Tags: drush, database

A drupal 7 website I am developing is repeatingly crashing. After each crash, I can't access any further pages on the website, in any browser, until I restore the database from a backup and remove half of the modules from the sites/all/modules directory.

The error I get on the browser is "connection reset". Each time I restore from a backup ( I have to remove about half of the modules from the sites/all/modules directory so it will start working), it crashes again at the same points:

- When I enter **any** content type fields editing screen, all I see is 'connection reset' error. (on some other pages it happends too).
- When I try to run a database-related drush command (including drush db-drop), I get a **segmentation fault** message.

Initial Analysis:

- That database is OK, at least from the MySQL point of view.
- When I restore it, it doesn't work until I remove about half of the modules.
- PHP memory limit is 800M so that's not the issue. It seems some of the modules have compatibility problems but how do I find which (No errors appear on the server's error log - the crashes are not logged).
- There might be some confusion inside the Drupal tables (e.g. content type definitions or menu definitions).

My questions:

- Which tools can I use to debug such a situation?
- What are the possible causes?
- How do I check for internal inconsistency insider the drupal respository definitions?

The site is hosted on a linux server with CentOS

Thanks

Amnon

Comment: Taking a stab here...what's the `max_allowed_packet` variable in my.cnf set to at the moment?

Comment: Did you try to set up the site in your local machine or test environment to discard a problem with Drupal. It sounds like your problem is server related, as Clive mentioned it might be a problem with max_allowed_packet

Comment: Added an 'Initial Analysis' section above and additional notes: After each crash, I can't access any further pages on the website, in any browser, until I restore the database from a backup and remove about half of the modules from the sites/all/modules directory. Will try your suggestions soon.

Comment: @clive, max_allowed_packet is 500M at the moment.

Comment: @cayerdis, I tried to set it up on a local testing environment (Acquia Dev Desktop) but it behaves the same - I get crashed on the same points.

Comment: It was a PHP error. The moment I reverted to earlier backup of the PHP files, everything was fixed (so it was seemingly related to a version of one of the modules). The drupal data repository remained intact.